# Reorder items in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that has the following columns: (id, position, etc.). Position indicates a sort order. How can I rearrange position of items. For example, if I want to rearrange the item at position 3 to position 5 or vice-versa, how can I achieve this?

As requested here is some sample data:

```
id  position name
==  ======== ======
1       5     Fred
2       3     Wilma
3       1     Betty
4       2     Barney
5       4     Pebbles
```

So if I do a `select * from customer order by position` I get:

```
id position name
== ======== =======
3      1     Betty
4      2     Barney
2      3     Wilma
5      4     Pebbles
1      5     Fred
```

I might then want to move Fred up in the list, say to position 3. I would then like the list to look like this:

```
id position name
== ======== =======
3      1     Betty
4      2     Barney
1      3     Fred
2      4     Wilma
5      5     Pebbles
```

My question is, how do I move an item either up or down in the list and get the positions to adjust accordingly?

I guess it would also be important to make sure that there are no missing or repeated position numbers.

Comment: please provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: you can use order by clause to sort the table.

Comment: Please explain your problem with some sample data. Going by your question it looks like a simple order by clause would do the trick

Comment: @AniketKariya My question was not about sorting the table, but rearranging items by position. Please see my update question for clarification.

Comment: @fa06 I have provided some sample data.

Comment: There is no discernible logic to what your trying to do so you are forced to hard code.

Comment: This is a standard 'drag-drop' re-order pattern, so you will find tutorials which cover it.

Comment: @P.Salmon Can you explain what you mean by discernible logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this UPDATE example the pos_from and pos_to have to be set.

The position with pos_from will be changed to pos_to.
And the others that need to shift up or down are corrected with +1 or -1 accordingly.

The pos_from can be higher or lower than the pos_to.

> ```
> create table bedrock (
>   id int primary key auto_increment, 
>   position int not null, 
>   name varchar(30) not null
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into  bedrock (position, name) values
> (5, 'Fred'),
> (3, 'Wilma'),
> (1, 'Betty'),
> (2, 'Barney'),
> (4, 'Pebbles');
> ```

> ```
> select * from bedrock order by position;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | position | name   
> -: | -------: | :------
>  3 |        1 | Betty  
>  4 |        2 | Barney 
>  2 |        3 | Wilma  
>  5 |        4 | Pebbles
>  1 |        5 | Fred
> ```

> ```
> update bedrock
> join
> (
>   select pos_from, pos_to, 
>   case when pos_to > pos_from then pos_from else pos_to end as pos_min,
>   case when pos_to > pos_from then pos_to else pos_from end as pos_max,
>   case when pos_to > pos_from then -1 else 1 end as pos_delta
>   from (
>     select 
>     5 as pos_from, 
>     3 as pos_to
>   ) q1
> ) q2 on position between pos_min and pos_max
> set position = case 
>                when position = pos_from 
>                then pos_to 
>                else position + pos_delta 
>                end;
> ```

> ```
> select * from bedrock order by position;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | position | name   
> -: | -------: | :------
>  3 |        1 | Betty  
>  4 |        2 | Barney 
>  1 |        3 | Fred   
>  2 |        4 | Wilma  
>  5 |        5 | Pebbles
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aab358e75a67501f4ba49b80c59afaeb)*

Comment: This is brilliant and took me a while to understand everything. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a stored procedure to update position:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN param1 INT, IN param2 INT)
BEGIN
   UPDATE sampleTable SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= param2;
   UPDATE sampleTable SET position = param2 WHERE id = param1;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Just make sure that position is not set as primary key, i know you want it unique; but it can cause problems with procedure.

btw, param1 is id of record which you want to update and param2 is position that you want to set.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It works just fine.

Comment: Does this work for moving both up and down in the list?

Answer (score -1):

I hope, you are expecting this below query.

```
select *,case when position = 3 then 5 when position = 5 then 3 else position end as new_position from customer order by new_position
```

Comment: My guess is that when someone moves up the board, everyone below them moves down 1